# QT / opencv : LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file : cannot read at 0x3F8 libopencv_core400.dll

Tags: qt, opencv

It's my first time using opencv and i'm having isue finding where the error could be, i followed this tutorial to install everything (https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows)

but i keep getting this error whenever i try to compile :

> D:\opencv\releases\bin\libopencv_core400.dll:-1: erreur : LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x3F8 libopencv_core400.dll

The other issue is that the solution for this error is to link against a .lib but opencv only has .dll on my computer

.pro

```
    INCLUDEPATH += D:\opencv\build\include
    LIBS += D:\opencv\releases\bin\libopencv_core400.dll
    LIBS += D:\opencv\releases\bin\libopencv_calib3d400.dll
    LIBS += D:\opencv\releases\bin\libopencv_highgui400.dll
    LIBS += D:\opencv\releases\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs400.dll
    LIBS += D:\opencv\releases\bin\libopencv_imgproc400.dll
    LIBS += D:\opencv\releases\bin\libopencv_features2d400.dll
```

Comment: dll are not libraries... those are needed to run the program. To compile you need the lib files, but maybe I am wrong

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the _[qmake variable manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs)_. The `LIBS` command should be `LIBS += -LD:/opencv/releases/bin`. You may also need to include `-l` flags on _[library dependencies](https://wiki.qt.io/Show_library_dependencies#Windows)_. Hope this helps!

Comment: @api55 is right, the recipe is for MinGW and contains typos. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886085/error-c-opencv-qt-build-bin-libopencv-core320-dll-1-error-lnk1107-invalid), place dlls near executable and link with libs

Answer (score 0):

This is an older thread, but maybe anybody with the same problem can make some use of it:

You can only use the built OpenCV-libraries for build-configurations using the same compiler. In your case: MinGW_32.
If you try to build your project with another build configuration, e.g. MSVC2017, you'll get these errors.

Selecting MinGW 32-bit as build configuraition fixed it for me.